# How to set items of legend next to themselves?

Tags: gnuplot

I use:

```
set key out horiz bot center
```

and I have items of legend under themselves. How to set them next to themselves? I write horiz, not vert, so why is it vert?

Comment: please show a complete minimal example of code and the resulting graph!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `help key`? What exactly is your problem?

**Code:**

```
### key vertical/horizontal
reset session

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set key out bot vert center
    plot x, x**2, x**3 w l

    set key out bot horiz center
    replot

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]